# ngModel' deep objects creation mechanism

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I want to use angular' mechanism for deep property nesting , something that `ng-model` directive is using. I mean we can create very "deep" object in a scope by writing : `ng-model="data.obj1.prop2.attr3.value4.text"` in a view , so i want to do it easily in a controller/service too. I don't want to reinvent a wheel (or use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631198/1206613) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15524326/1206613)). Is there something undocumented like `angular.create(path_str)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can achieve is by using `$parse` service. It has `getter` and `setter` function that i think can handle what you want

```
    var getter = $parse('prop1.prop2.prop3.prop4');
    var setter = getter.assign;
    setter($scope,"value1111");
```

See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/m7gxn/

And i think this also works

```
$scope.$eval("prop2.prop2.prop3.prop4=55");
```

Comment: This is how `ngModel` does it too.

Comment: great, i'll test it in a minute