# AngularJS - Deep object' property deletion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I know how to set object' "deep" property with [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse) service , like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19317848/ngmodel-deep-objects-creation-mechanism).

But how can i delete a deep property ? Not assign it to `null` with this:

```
$parse('very.very.deep.property').assign($scope, null);
```

, but actually delete it, like we're doing it in JavaScript:

```
delete $scope.very.very.deep.property;
```

Comment: sure seems like  `delete $parse('very.very.deep.property')` should work

Comment: @charlietfl no , i thought that `delete $parse('very.very.deep.property').assign($scope)` will work, but it only sets the `property`  to `undefined` : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/2Evxq/

Comment: so am curious why you can't use `delete $scope.very.very.deep.property;` because that does leave `deep` as empty object and `hasOwnProperty('property')` is false

Comment: @charlietfl because this part : `very.very.deep.property` come to me as a string from server.. in the end it is translated to XML node and is a part of one big XML structure

Comment: ok...so do you have to recursively loop through deep nodes of the xml? If so while looping through mabe could keep adding `[nodeName]` then `[nodeName][childNodeName]` to scope at each level?

Comment: @charlietfl yes , i guess many workarounds can be found , but i'm very interested to find the real solution for the issue ;)

Comment: @charlietfl data chunk that contains this string comes in one server call with its small view , like : `<script type="data">node='very.very.deep.property'</script><div><input/></div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am afraid that there is no Angular service/function for what you are looking for. But you can still implement something like the following to fulfill your requirement :

```
function Ctrl($scope,$parse){
  var path = 'very.very.deep.property';
  var partials = path.split('.');
  var deepKey = partials.pop(); //Extract the key name from your path
  var deepPath = partials.join('.'); //Build the parent's path
  var deep = $parse(deepPath);
  var prop = $parse(path);
  prop.assign($scope, "I'm so deep");
  delete deep($scope)[deepKey]; //Evaluate the deep path against your scope and delete the key
  console.log(deepKey, $scope.very.very.deep)
}
```

A fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Evxq/2/). Hope this would come handy.