# how to recursively loop inside object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get all the values of the object and compare

Object :

```
obj = {
     a : 10,
     b : [{b1 : 101 , b2:201},{b3 : 102 , b4:204}],
     c : [{c1 : 107 , c2:209 ,d :[{d1:109},{d2:402}]}]
}

function compareValues(101,obj) {           

   if (retriveValueFromObject(obj,101)) {
       return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   } 

   function comparator(a, b) {
       return ('' + a).toLowerCase().indexOf(('' + b).toLowerCase()) > -1;
   }
}
```

**Pending** : 
**retriveValueFromObject**()   need to be implemented such a way that i will loop in to all the key value pair of the object and send back flag(t/f) if value is in the object.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when voting down so that the question can be improved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
function retriveValueFromObject(theObject, value) {
  for(var prop in theObject) {
      if(theObject[prop] == value) {
        return true;
      }
      if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array)
       return getObject(theObject[prop]);
  }
  return false;
}
```

I found this here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15524326/1062711

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
function retrieveValueFromObject(obj,101) {
    var result;
    for (var key in obj){
        if (typeof(obj[key]) !== 'Object')
            result = comperator(101, obj[key]);
        else
            result = retrieveValueFromObject(obj[key],101);
    }
    return result;
}
```

didn't get to test it myself, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to retrieve all values from object recursively into array and then check with `Array.prototype.indexOf()`:

```
function getValues(obj) {
    var result = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var curVal = obj[key];
            if (typeof (curVal) === 'object') {
                result = result.concat(getValues(curVal));
            } else {
                result.push(curVal);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
console.log(getValues(o));
console.log(getValues(o).indexOf(101) !== -1);
console.log(getValues(o).indexOf('nosuchvalue') !== -1);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff5rT/)**