# Angular: How to search in nested array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a function that will search/filter the biggest value in a nested array and then return parent scope.

My array looks next:

```
 data = {"people": 
   [{"male": [
     {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}, 
     {"name":"Mike", "age":"22"}
    ]}, 
   {"female": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"}, 
     {"name":"Ann", "age": "23"}
   ]}]}
```

And I need to find the biggest age value from all people and then return back male or female array (in example this is male array)

With javascript I can use something like:

```
largest = array.reduce((x, y) ->
      if x > y then x else y
    )
    console.log largest
```

but how this can be implement to nested array?

Or is there a way to use angular `$filter`?

Comment: It's not a nested array you're using. it's an object whcih has some properties with their values being an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see here for how to search a nested object: [Find by key deep in a nested object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523514/find-by-key-deep-in-nested-json-object)

Then you can just loop through all the items in your array to search them.

I would suggest a rather different approach, if you can guarantee the structure of your array and those nested objects.
First you loop through the array (male/female), and for each of them you loop through the persons and find their age.
Its not exact code but something of the likes of:

```
var age = 0;
data["people"].forEach(function(item) { 
    for (var key in item) {
        if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            item[key].forEach(function(person) {
                if (person.age > age) {
                    age = person.age;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
console.log(age);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works great. Based on this example what is the best way to find next biggest age value (in my data example it will be `"age": "24"`)?

Comment: Off the top of my head, after finding the largest age - remove that person from the list and re-run the function. That would probably be the least-code solution, but not very efficient. If you are potentially working with tens of thousand of people entry's, you should just have age1 and age2 variables, and update them both sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly data representation but anyway:

```
var data = {"people": 
   [{"male": [
     {"name": "Bob" ,"age": "32"}, 
     {"name":"Mike", "age":"22"}
    ]}, 
   {"female": [
     {"name":"Jessica", "age": "24"}, 
     {"name":"Ann", "age": "23"}
   ]}]};

function getMaxAge(array) {
  var max = 0;
  array.forEach(function(people) {
    if (people.age > max) max = people.age;
  })
  return max;
}

var max = 0;
var arrayWithMax;
for (var i = 0; i < data.people.length; i++) {
  var array = data.people[i][Object.keys(data.people[i])[0]];
  var currentMax = getMaxAge(array);
  if (currentMax > max) {
    max = currentMax;
    arrayWithMax = array;
  }
}

console.log('max age: ' + max)
console.log(arrayWithMax);
```

See this code working in https://jsfiddle.net/ave5hcLu/

I'm assuming your data structure is fixed