# Finding an object deep in a nested json object

Tags: javascript, json, object, lodash

I have the nested json object in the snippet below and want to find all occurrences of '$schema' and save the whole object that contains that schema value into another object. I tried using lodash filter but, was unsuccessful. Does anyone have any recommendations.

```js
{
  "element": "parseResult",
  "content": [
    {
      "element": "category",
      "meta": {
        "classes": [
          "api"
        ],
        "title": "Test"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "meta": [
          {
            "element": "member",
            "meta": {
              "classes": [
                "user"
              ]
            },
            "content": {
              "key": {
                "element": "string",
                "content": "FORMAT"
              },
              "value": {
                "element": "string",
                "content": "1A"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "content": [
        {
          "element": "category",
          "meta": {
            "classes": [
              "resourceGroup"
            ],
            "title": "Questions"
          },
          "content": [
            {
              "element": "resource",
              "meta": {
                "title": "Questions"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "href": "/questions"
              },
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "transition",
                  "meta": {
                    "title": "List All Questions"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "httpTransaction",
                      "content": [
                        {
                          "element": "httpRequest",
                          "attributes": {
                            "method": "GET"
                          },
                          "content": []
                        },
                        {
                          "element": "httpResponse",
                          "attributes": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "headers": {
                              "element": "httpHeaders",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "member",
                                  "content": {
                                    "key": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "Content-Type"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "application/json"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "content": [
                            {
                              "element": "dataStructure",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "Question List"
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBody"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/json"
                              },
                              "content": "[\n  {\n    \"question\": \"Favourite programming language?\",\n    \"published_at\": \"2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z\",\n    \"url\": \"/questions/1\",\n    \"choices\": [\n      {\n        \"choice\": \"Javascript\",\n        \"url\": \"/questions/1/choices/1\",\n        \"votes\": 2048\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n]"
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBodySchema"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/schema+json"
                              },
                              "content": "{\n  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n  \"type\": \"array\"\n}"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "element": "resource",
              "meta": {
                "title": "Question"
              },
              "attributes": {
                "href": "/questions/{id}",
                "hrefVariables": {
                  "element": "hrefVariables",
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "id"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "number",
                          "content": 1234
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "transition",
                  "meta": {
                    "title": "Retrieve Question"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "httpTransaction",
                      "content": [
                        {
                          "element": "httpRequest",
                          "attributes": {
                            "method": "GET"
                          },
                          "content": []
                        },
                        {
                          "element": "httpResponse",
                          "attributes": {
                            "statusCode": "200",
                            "headers": {
                              "element": "httpHeaders",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "member",
                                  "content": {
                                    "key": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "Content-Type"
                                    },
                                    "value": {
                                      "element": "string",
                                      "content": "application/json"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          "content": [
                            {
                              "element": "dataStructure",
                              "content": [
                                {
                                  "element": "Question"
                                }
                              ]
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBody"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/json"
                              },
                              "content": "{\n  \"question\": \"Favourite programming language?\",\n  \"published_at\": \"2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z\",\n  \"url\": \"/questions/1\",\n  \"choices\": [\n    {\n      \"choice\": \"Javascript\",\n      \"url\": \"/questions/1/choices/1\",\n      \"votes\": 2048\n    }\n  ]\n}"
                            },
                            {
                              "element": "asset",
                              "meta": {
                                "classes": [
                                  "messageBodySchema"
                                ]
                              },
                              "attributes": {
                                "contentType": "application/schema+json"
                              },
                              "content": "{\n  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n  \"type\": \"object\",\n  \"properties\": {\n    \"question\": {\n      \"type\": \"string\"\n    },\n    \"published_at\": {\n      \"type\": \"string\"\n    },\n    \"url\": {\n      \"type\": \"string\"\n    },\n    \"choices\": {\n      \"type\": \"array\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"required\": [\n    \"question\",\n    \"published_at\",\n    \"url\",\n    \"choices\"\n  ]\n}"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "element": "category",
          "meta": {
            "classes": [
              "dataStructures"
            ]
          },
          "content": [
            {
              "element": "dataStructure",
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "object",
                  "meta": {
                    "id": "Question"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "question"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "Favourite programming language?"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "published_at"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "2014-11-11T08:40:51.620Z"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "url"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "/questions/1"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "choices"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "array",
                          "content": [
                            {
                              "element": "Choice"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "element": "dataStructure",
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "object",
                  "meta": {
                    "id": "Choice"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "choice"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "Javascript"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "url"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "/questions/1/choices/1"
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "element": "member",
                      "attributes": {
                        "typeAttributes": [
                          "required"
                        ]
                      },
                      "content": {
                        "key": {
                          "element": "string",
                          "content": "votes"
                        },
                        "value": {
                          "element": "number",
                          "content": 2048
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "element": "dataStructure",
              "content": [
                {
                  "element": "array",
                  "meta": {
                    "id": "Question List"
                  },
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "element": "Question"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried this as a solution.

```
function getObject(theObject) {
        var result = null;
        if(theObject instanceof Array) {
            for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {
                result = getObject(theObject[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(var prop in theObject) {
                console.log(prop + ': ' + theObject[prop]);
                if(prop == '$schema') {
                    if(theObject[prop] == 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#') {
                        return theObject;
                    }
                }
                if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array)
                    result = getObject(theObject[prop]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    var result = getObject(json);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception or error, post the line it occurred on and the details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Why are you using both lodash and underscore?

Comment: I have reworked my question any help would be great thanks.

Comment: The `$schema` is part of the `String` value of the deeply nested `content` key. Try `JSON.parse` of that string value and then look for the `$schema` property.

Comment: @Abhishek do you mean trying to parse only the content portion of the object? Or do you mean trying to parse the whole object? Because I did do JSON.parse on the whole object.

Comment: @JacobBrauchler Parse the value of content key. But you have to be careful as the value of each key isn't in JSON form, so you may get errors if you are not selective while parsing.

Comment: @Abhishek How should I approach parsing that? I am unsure as to how to parse a section of an object that is already parsed.

Comment: I'm looking closely at your parsed object to make sure it has what you think it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jacob,

The problem is in your JSON itself. Your json is a key/value pair.  Keys can be strings (surrounded with "quotes") to enable properties that have spaces or special characters. e.g.

```
var obj = { "my property": "my value" };
var val = obj["my property"] // "my value";
```

However your values should only have quotes around them if they are strings, otherwise it won't get parsed to an object - it will remain in string representation.

```
var obj = { "foo" : "{ \"bar\" : \"my value\" }" } // notice I had to escape the strings with backslashes \
var val = obj.foo.bar // error because foo is a string with the value "{ "bar" : "my value" }"
```

In your json, the value of the content property is a string:

```
"content": "{\n  \"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#\",\n  \"type\": \"array\"\n}"
```

The fact that you needed to escape your quotes with \ tells you this as well.  If you expect the content to be parsed the first time, then it should look something like this:

```
"content": { "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#", "type": "array" }
```

If you can't change this, then you can call an [eval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) or a [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the content to parse the string to an object (this can be unsafe if your content is coming from the users).

Edit:
Because you cannot change the JSON coming in, I created a function called deepParseObject.  It's by no means error-proof, but I think it will work for your situation:

```
function deepParseObject(theObject) {
  for(var prop in theObject) {
      if(typeof theObject[prop] === "string" && (theObject[prop].indexOf('{') == 0 || theObject[prop].indexOf('[') == 0)) {
          theObject[prop] = JSON.parse(theObject[prop]);
      }
      if(theObject[prop] instanceof Object || theObject[prop] instanceof Array)
          deepParseObject(theObject[prop]);
  }
}
```

What it does is parse the content properties if their values are strings and start with a `{` or `[`.  After that you can call my original getObject function.  Here is the plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/h06wuAxZkxhwCAho3OK6

I call deepParseObject in the data.js and I'm only using AngularJS to output the results... and because I like Angular :).

[image]

Comment: I am reading it in from drafted and am attempting to make it so that I can get those objects for any Json file. I am just parsing the output I receive from drafter. Would giving you my drafter output help to determine why it is not parsing correctly when I'm trying to parse the string in the first place?

Comment: Okay I just edited and made sure that the snippet is what is output by drafter, so that would be completely unparsed.

Comment: Is this the drafter you're using?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/drafter

Comment: I'm using drafter-Head from homebrew

Comment: I'm using drafter-Head from homebrew

Comment: Updated answer with solution to deal with output.

Comment: Thank you so much this was a huge help. Would there be a good way to make get Object find all instances of `"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"`?

Comment: Create an array and push each instance onto the array in the getObject function.  This would replace the `return theObject;`.  You would also have to remove the `break` so that it fully recurses the object.

Comment: I'm going to try and get it working on the plunker if you see I'm doing something stupid please let me know

Comment: I already did it for you... https://plnkr.co/edit/MPBkDKe3u3TYOGQhRJ2S Notice that the getObject no longer returns a result.  It takes an array as a parameter and fully recurses the object given as a first parameter.  `vm.result = [];` declares the array and `getObject(obj, vm.result);` is the call.