# Check if a text exists in a value in deep nested object?

Tags: javascript, object

How is it possible to check if a deep nested object containing a value?
I want to check if the given object contains for example, a property value that contains "where" :

```
let data = {
    name: 'Somebody',
    address: {
        city: 'somewhere'
    },
    tags: [{
        id: 5
        name: 'new'
    }]
}
check(data, 'where') // should be true
```

Comment: It's possible with recursion.

Comment: Easiest way would be a recursive function that calls itself on each iterable sub-object, and checks any strings. I don't think there's a built-in for this.

Comment: You want `where` to be a substring?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523514/find-by-key-deep-in-a-nested-object

Comment: can `where` be a part of value, be a key, part of key, ???

Comment: Yes, should be a kind of search

Comment: @ Rajshekar Reddy: Should be a part of the value

Comment: Write a recursive function that checks whether a property is an object. If so run the recursive function one level deeper on that nested object. if the property is not an object, but a value check if it matches the property you are searching for and check the value based on your criteria.

Comment: @Rajesh: I'm only looking for the values, not for the keys

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `recursive function` as below which is iterating over the keys and checking for the type. If the type is `object` or `array`, it will invoke recursive check.

**Working snippet**:

```js
let data = {
    name: 'Somebody',
    address: {
        city: 'somewhere'
    },
    tags: [{
        id: 5,
        name: 'new'
    }]
};

const check = (obj, text) => {
  var exists = false;
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    var type = typeof obj[key];
    if(type === 'object') {
      exists = check(obj[key], text);
    } else if(type === 'array') {
      
      for(var j = 0; j < obj[key].length; j++) {
        exists = check(obj[key][j], text);
    
        if(exists) {
          break;
        }
      }
      
    } else if(type === 'string') {
      exists = obj[key].indexOf(text) > -1;
    }
    
    if(exists) {
      break;
    }
  }
       
  return exists;
};

console.log(check(data, 'where')); // should be true
```