# how to get object by passing id in an array of nested objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

example data :

```
var data = [
{a:{id: "1",name: "alex",class: "1"}},
{a:{id: "2",name: "john",class: "2"}},
{a:{id: "3",name: "ketty",class: "3"}}
]
```

if i pass id as 1 result : [{name:"john",class:"1"}].

please help me with the above question please.

Comment: Are you sure it's `[{name:"john,class:"1"}]` not `[{name:"alex,class:"1"}]` ?

Comment: it is like this [{name:"john",class:"1"}]

Comment: Did you mean [{name:"john",class:"2"}] ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find by key deep in a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523514/find-by-key-deep-in-a-nested-array)

Comment: please edit your question and explain clearly your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.find()` to get an item with the path of `a.id` that equals the `id` you are looking for. Then use `_.get()` to take the item out of the `a` property, and omit the `id`.

**Note**: This will give you a single item, and not an array of a single item. You can always wrap it in an array, if you absolutely need it.

```js
const { flow, find, get, omit } = _

const fn = id => flow(
  arr => find(arr, ['a.id', id]), // find the item which has the id
  item => get(item, 'a'), // extract it from a
  item => omit(item, 'id'), // remove the id
)

const data = [{"a":{"id":"1","name":"alex","class":"1"}},{"a":{"id":"2","name":"john","class":"2"}},{"a":{"id":"3","name":"ketty","class":"3"}}]

const result = fn('1')(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can just state the iteratees (the properties you wish to use), since lodash/fp functions are curried, and iteratees first:

```js
const { flow, find, get, omit } = _

const fn = id => flow(
  find(['a.id', id]),
  get('a'),
  omit('id'),
)

const data = [{"a":{"id":"1","name":"alex","class":"1"}},{"a":{"id":"2","name":"john","class":"2"}},{"a":{"id":"3","name":"ketty","class":"3"}}]

const result = fn('1')(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

its really simple to do:-

```
var data = [
{a:{id: "1",name: "alex",class: "1"}},
{a:{id: "2",name: "john",class: "2"}},
{a:{id: "3",name: "ketty",class: "3"}}
]
let idToFind = 1;
let filtered = data.filter(f=>f['a']['id']==idToFind);
```