# How to find a value in multilevel Array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a search box in which if i start searching for a value it will look for the target in an nested array of objects which is like this:--

```
[
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "groupName": "Americas",
    "groupItems": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Brazil",
        "parentID": 1,
        "parentName": "Americas"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Canada",
        "parentID": 1,
        "parentName": "Americas"
      }
    ],
    "isExpanded": false,
    "toggleAllSelection": false
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "groupName": "APAC",
    "groupItems": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Australia",
        "parentID": 2,
        "parentName": "APAC"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "China",
        "parentID": 2,
        "parentName": "APAC"
      }
    ],
    "isExpanded": false,
    "toggleAllSelection": false
  },
  {
    "groupId": 3,
    "groupName": "Europe",
    "groupItems": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Belgium",
        "parentID": 3,
        "parentName": "Europe"
      },
{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Austria",
        "parentID": 2,
        "parentName": "APAC"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Bulgaria",
        "parentID": 3,
        "parentName": "Europe"
      }
    ],
    "isExpanded": false,
    "toggleAllSelection": false
  }
]
```

Now i want to search for `name` property in each `groupItems` array of objects in `group` array. and when there is a match my function should return data in same format and as it will be autocomplete so instead of exact match it should be partial match. So if search `aus` in input box it should return

```
[{
    "groupId": 2,
    "groupName": "APAC",
    "groupItems": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Australia",
        "parentID": 2,
        "parentName": "APAC"
      }],
    "isExpanded": false,
    "toggleAllSelection": false,
},
{
    "groupId": 3,
    "groupName": "Europe",
    "groupItems": [
       {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Austria",
        "parentID": 2,
        "parentName": "APAC"
      }
    ],
    "isExpanded": false,
    "toggleAllSelection": false
  }

]
```

Comment: what u have tried ?? add minimal code

Comment: Ok. Sure. Let me add.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find by key deep in a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523514/find-by-key-deep-in-a-nested-array)

Comment: So for more information,  I have had implemented a solution but I wasn't sure if its right way to do it :-- 
I'm flattening the array filtering through group items and grouping them again based on parentId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const findByName = (data, name) => {
  const result = data.reduce((m, { groupItems, ...rest }) => {
    let mapGrpItems = (groupItems || []).filter((item) =>
      item.name.includes(name)
    );
    if (mapGrpItems.length) {
      m.push({ ...rest, groupItems: mapGrpItems });
    }
    return m;
  }, []);
  return result;
};
```

```js
const findByName = (data, name) => {
  const result = data.reduce((m, { groupItems, ...rest }) => {
    let mapGrpItems = (groupItems || []).filter((item) =>
      item.name.includes(name)
    );
    if (mapGrpItems.length) {
      m.push({ ...rest, groupItems: mapGrpItems });
    }
    return m;
  }, []);
  return result;
};

const data = [{"groupId":1,"groupName":"Americas","groupItems":[{"id":5,"name":"Brazil","parentID":1,"parentName":"Americas"},{"id":6,"name":"Canada","parentID":1,"parentName":"Americas"}],"isExpanded":false,"toggleAllSelection":false},{"groupId":2,"groupName":"APAC","groupItems":[{"id":7,"name":"Australia","parentID":2,"parentName":"APAC"},{"id":8,"name":"China","parentID":2,"parentName":"APAC"}],"isExpanded":false,"toggleAllSelection":false},{"groupId":3,"groupName":"Europe","groupItems":[{"id":9,"name":"Belgium","parentID":3,"parentName":"Europe"},{"id":7,"name":"Austria","parentID":2,"parentName":"APAC"},{"id":10,"name":"Bulgaria","parentID":3,"parentName":"Europe"}],"isExpanded":false,"toggleAllSelection":false}]
console.log(JSON.stringify(findByName(data, "Aus"), null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely attempt to reason through what you're trying to do before just implementing this. Being able to reason through solutions like this is 99% of the job when it comes to programming.

```js
function filterGroups(filter) {
  const result = [];

  myObj.forEach(group => {
    const filteredGroups = group.groupItems.filter(groupItem => {
      return groupItem.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
    });

    if (filteredGroups.length > 1) {
      result.push({
        ...group,
        groupItems: filteredGroups
      });
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for the group items in each outer object in your JSON array to filter out the items which match your search query. You can write something like this:

```
let autocomplete = (key) => { 
  // arr = Your Data
  let result = []
  arr.forEach(grp=> {
  let out = grp
  let res = grp.groupItems.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase()))
  if(res.length!=0)
  {
    out.groupItems = res
    result.push(out)}
})
return result
```