# How can I acces to object I know to key dynamically like tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, sorting, tree

I have dynamic data tree structure like below but data is changeable (for example could be added children to id: 6) element, I want to access it I know id name node for example id is 7 I access it like that

> tree.children[0].children[0].children[1]

but if i only knew id name and how could I find it from the given tree structure if I didn't know what node it was in
for better understanding for example Im just know the id is 7 I want to tree.children[0].children[0].children[1] this path how can I do dynamically

```
  let tree = {
    id: 1,
    name: "tree1",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "tree2",
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "tree4",
            children: [
              {
                id: 6,
                name: "tree6"
              },
              {
                id: 7,
                name: "tree7"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: "tree5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "tree3"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Comment: Please do not delete your question this time. I was working on a solution and could not submit it because you deleted your previous question :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find by key deep in a nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523514/find-by-key-deep-in-a-nested-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
let tree = {
    id: 1,
    name: "tree1",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "tree2",
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            name: "tree4",
            children: [
              {
                id: 6,
                name: "tree6"
              },
              {
                id: 7,
                name: "tree7"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            name: "tree5"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "tree3"
      }
    ]
  };
  
const findById = (id, obj, path = 'tree') => {
    if (obj.id === id) return [obj, path];
    else if (obj.children) {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
            const [child, p] = findById(id, obj.children[i], path + `.children[${i}]`);
            if (child) {
                return [child, p];
            }
        }
    }
    return [null, path];
}

console.log(findById(7, tree, 'tree'));
```

Comment: I want acces to id's 7 element path like tree.children[0].children[0].children[1]

Comment: Yes is path is correct but let path = findById(7, tree, 'tree') then path[2] is string not giving to this {id: 7, name: "tree7"}, how can I do that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  If you do `const [obj, path] = findById(7, tree, 'tree');`, then you have the object and the string path.  If you want to use the path to get to the item, you could do `eval(path)` and it will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
let tree = {
  id: 1,
  name: "tree1",
  children: [{
      id: 2,
      name: "tree2",
      children: [{
          id: 4,
          name: "tree4",
          children: [{
              id: 6,
              name: "tree6"
            },
            {
              id: 7,
              name: "tree7"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "tree5"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "tree3"
    }
  ]
};

const findNodeById = (node, id) => {
  if (node.id === id) {
    return node
  } else if (node.children && node.children.length > 0) {
    for (let child of node.children) {
      node = findNodeById(child, id);
      if (node)
        return node
    }
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const node = findNodeById(tree, 7);
console.log(node);
```

Comment: I want acces to id's 7 element path like tree.children[0].children[0].children[1]

Answer (score -2):

To access it use `document.getElementById("tree7", "tree 6")`. Then just add some execssive content. Or use a variable

```js
var tree6 = document.getElementById("tree6");
var tree7 = document.getElementById("tree7");

var treesomething = tree6 + tree7;
```

Comment: The question doesn't  say this tree is a tree of DOM elements. This solution makes an assumption I don't think is accurate.